# Any way to programmatically disable hardware accelerated h.264 video decoding in silverlight 5?

Tags: macos, video, h.264, silverlight-5.0, hardware-acceleration

We are getting reports from our Mac users that some of their video is playing back garbled. This only started happening when Silverlight 5 was released. This release included hardware video decoding acceleration for H.264, which is the codec we use. We have found that disabling the hardware acceleration through the Silverlight Preferences solves the problem.

Does anyone know of a **programmatic** way of disabling the hardware acceleration? We have thousands of users on OS X, and would like to preemptively fix this issue for them. Other ways of solving the issue from our end would also be welcome.

Relevant details:

- H.264 codec in MP4 container, sometimes with AAC audio
- Video is hosted on Amazon S3 and fed through a CDN
- Using the Silverlight [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- I have tried turning off [enableGPUAcceleration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in the object params
- I have tried turning off the [CacheMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cachemode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) since it affects GPU acceleration as detailed [on this page about Silverlight hardware acceleration.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309563%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

**Update**

- It doesn't happen consistently, which is making this problem harder to solve. Some videos will play OK, and others will not. All the videos are encoded the same way.
- It happens in Google Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.
- This is **Mac OS X only**, it doesn't happen at all in Windows.
- It happens on several different models and revisions of Macs. Mac Mini, MacBook Air, MacBook Pro, etc. We haven't found a particular model that never has the issue so far.

**Update 2**

- Reproduces with Silverlight 5.0 and 5.1

**Update 3**

- This is in-browser (hence the browsers listed above)

Here is an example of the garbled video

[image: silverlight 5 garbled video]

The preferences setting that fixes the issue

[image: silverlight preferences]

Comment: Have you opened a bug at Microsoft Connect (https://connect.microsoft.com/)?

Comment: I haven't yet. I was hoping we could find a workaround since a bugfix will take some time.

Comment: I agree that an official bugfix might take a long time, but raising the awareness at Microsoft about the issue might still help, and maybe they'll have a workaround to suggest.

Comment: Hi @BryceKahle.. did you find a solution for this? we are also experiencing the same problem you had mentioned above. we also have many mac users...

Comment: @AllanChua unfortunately, no. There currently isn't a way to programmatically disable it.

Comment: Please provide a sample file that reproduces the problem - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned several browsers, so I assume you're hosted on a page. See if this does it for you:

```
<param name="enableGPUAcceleration" value="false"/>
```

in the `<object>` tag on the HTML page hosting the plug-in.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried that and it doesn't work. I can't be 100% sure, but after reading much of the documentation, that flag doesn't seem to apply to the video decoder acceleration.

Comment: Sorry, missed that in your comments. (It seems I keep reading the text and finding things I missed. Maybe I'm tired ;)

Answer (score 0):

If it is Out of browser application you can turn off GPU Acceleration in OOB settings [image]

Comment: Is it not an Out of Browser application unfortunately. I have a feeling that does the same thing as the enableGPUAcceleration object param I've already tried.